Camera & IMU .bag recording
I am currently trying to work with the camera and IMU data and it needs to by synchronized However, I tried to record data using this command:
rosbag record -o abc.bag -b 200 imu camera/raw

When I process the data it differs in every run! Even that i am using the same abc.bag file.
Solutions I tried

rosbag reindex the .bag file
rosbag fix the .bag file
I didn't compress and decompress the data, I thought it might cause data loss

Please if you have any solution to assure the synch and the timestamp between IMU and camera or anything to try just let me know.

What is cz? Czech?

Or is it "because"? i.e. "cos" => "cz"? Also does the title mean "a bad recording" or ".bag recording"? Please fix all typos as your question is rather difficult to understand. I have tried to fix some of them for you. You are more likely to get a good answer if your question is able to be understood. Thanks.

To be able to help you we'll likely need an understanding of what you mean by this. "When I process the data it differs in every run!" What's different? It's unlikely that the bag is changing, so there's many other parts of your statement to look at. My first question is are you overloading the system such that data is being dropped?
